# Convolutional autoencoder not learning meaningful filters

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am playing with TensorFlow to understand convolutional autoencoders. I have implemented a simple single-layer autoencoder which does this:

Input (Dimension: 95x95x1) ---> Encoding (convolution with 32 5x5 filters) ---> Latent representation (Dimension: 95x95x1x32) ---> Decoding (using tied weights) ---> Reconstructed input (Dimension: 95x95x1)

The inputs are black-and-white edge images i.e. the results of edge detection on RGB images.

I initialised the filters randomly and then trained the model to minimise loss, where loss is defined as the mean-squared-error of the input and the reconstructed input.

```
loss = 0.5*(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(x,x_reconstructed))))
```

After training with 1000 steps, my loss converges and the network is able to reconstruct the images well. However, when I visualise the learned filters, they do not look very different from the randomly-initialised filters! But the values of the filters change from training step to training step.

[Example of learned filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrVqG.png)

I would have expected at least horizontal and vertical edge filters. Or if my network was learning "identity filters" I would have expected the filters to all be white or something?

Does anyone have any idea about this? Or are there any suggestions as to what I can do to analyse what is happening? Should I include pooling and depooling layers before decoding?

Thank you!

P/S: I tried the same model on RGB images and again the filters look random (like random blotches of colours).

Comment: You need regularization, do u have it?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov No, I am not using regularization at the moment. Just to confirm if my understanding is correct, I should add the regularization term to my loss function such that "large" weight values are penalized?

`loss = 0.5*(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(x,x_reconstructed)))) + lambda*(tf.reduce_mean(W_conv1))`

where lambda = regularization term and W_conv1 = matrix of encoding weights

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can get edge filters if you add sparsity penalty http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Autoencoders_and_Sparsity

Comment: Can we see full code ?